# Segmentation fault - Implementing Stack using Queues

Tags: c, struct, stack, queue

I'm implementing a stack using two queues. I'm quite familiar with the algorithm, and have prepared the following code where the push operation is costly:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct queue_struct{
    int ele;
    struct queue_struct *next;
};

struct Queue{
    struct queue_struct *front, *rear;
};

struct Stack{
    struct Queue *q1, *q2;
};

void enqueue(struct Queue *q, int x){
    struct queue_struct *temp=malloc(sizeof(*temp));
    temp->ele=x;
    temp->next=NULL;
    if(q->rear!=NULL){
        q->rear->next=temp;
    }
    q->rear=temp;
    if(q->front==NULL)
        q->front=temp;
    //printf("The item %d has been enqueued into the queue\n", x);
}

void dequeue(struct Queue *q){
    struct queue_struct *temp=q->front;
    if(temp==NULL){
        //printf("The queue is already empty. No more elements can be removed!\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("The item %d has been popped from the stack\n", temp->ele);
    q->front=temp->next;
    if(q->rear==temp)
        q->rear=NULL;
    free(temp);
}

void push(struct Stack *s, int x){
    enqueue(s->q2, x);
    while(!(s->q1->front==NULL)){
        enqueue(s->q2, s->q1->front->ele);
        dequeue(s->q1);
    }
    struct Queue *q=s->q1;
    s->q1=s->q2;
    s->q2=q;
    printf("The item %d has been pushed into the stack\n", x);
}

void pop(struct Stack *s){
    if(s->q1->front==NULL){
        printf("The stack is already empty. No more elements can be removed!\n");
        return;
    }
    dequeue(s->q1);
}

void display(struct Stack *s){
    struct queue_struct *temp=s->q1->front;
    printf("The contents of the queue are:\n");
    if(temp==NULL){
        printf("Nothing to be shown, the queue is empty.\n");
        return;
    }
    for(int i=0;temp!=NULL;temp=temp->next){
        if(i){
            printf(" ------ \n");
        }
        printf("|  %d  |\n", temp->ele);
        i=1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int choice, element;
    struct Stack *s=malloc(sizeof(*s));
    s->q1->front=s->q1->rear=NULL;
    s->q2->front=s->q2->rear=NULL;
    printf("LET'S START WITH AN EMPTY STACK\n\n");
    while(1){
        printf("MENU\n");
        printf("----\n");
        printf("\t1. Push an element\n");
        printf("\t2. Pop an element\n");
        printf("\t3. Display stack\n");
        printf("\t4. Exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch(choice){
            case 1: printf("Enter the element to be pushed: ");
                    scanf("%d", &element);
                    push(s, element);
                    break;
            case 2: pop(s);
                    break;
            case 3: display(s);
                    break;
            case 4: printf("Program terminated successfully!");
                    return 0;
            default: printf("Invalid input");
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting a Segmentation fault for the line(s): s->q1->front=s->q1->rear=NULL;. I'm not really sure why it is happening and how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like `q1` and `q2` members of `Stack` are uninitialized at that point.

Comment: You have only allocated `s`, but `s->q1`, yet you are trying to dereference it

Comment: @FredLarson but I have mentioned in  ```struct Stack``` that they are part of ```s```. Won't that be enough?

Comment: `s->q1` is a pointer. Where would it point to?

Comment: @FredLarson Oh, now I get it, I have to allocate memory for q1 and q2 too! Thanks

Comment: @Eugene Sh got it, thanks

Answer (score 4):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by using values in buffer allocated via `malloc()` and not initialized.

You have to initialize `s->q1` and `s->q2` before dereferencing them.

```
struct Stack *s=malloc(sizeof(*s));
if (s == NULL) return 1; /* check if allocation succeeded */
s->q1 = malloc(sizeof(*s->q1)); /* allocate for s->q1 */
s->q2 = malloc(sizeof(*s->q2)); /* allocate for s->q2 */
if (s->q1 == NULL || s->q2 == NULL) return 1; /* check if allocations succeeded */
s->q1->front=s->q1->rear=NULL;
s->q2->front=s->q2->rear=NULL;
```